# Can you use the Single Player mode on Team Fortress 2 to get Achievements?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2

There is now the option for one player mode, which is good for people to hone skills, and whatnot, but can you get achievements/drops in One Player? If so: how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In "offline practice mode" (where you play against bots):

- Statistics (e.g. longest life) are turned **off**
- Achievements **cannot** be received
- Item drops are **possible**

Source: [official tf2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Training), and also verified by personal experience.

Comment: You use to be able to get them with practice mode (except for taunt achievements) but they changed that around the time of the Uber Update....

Answer (score 8):

You cannot get achievements from the one player mode.

However, you *can* create an otherwise empty server to "farm" achievements (though, understandably, many of the achievements require at least two people), and you can even unlock achievements via LAN games.

Comment: +1, it does work to create an empty server and then do achievements in there by yourself (good uses for this are ones that involve capturing multiple intelligence or control points in a single round, since there's no one else to interfere)

Comment: I've found that in some map modes, if there is no other player, the timer will finish once 'waiting for other players' is finished. There isn't then any actual round time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get achievements using the "map" and the "tf_bot_add" commands. However, when using the practice mode, achievements are not possible.